# Subconsulta con Eloquent en donde se pueda traer campos omitiendo algunos registros

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de hacer una subconsulta en donde pueda traer mis campos omitiendo algunos registros.

**Esta es mi consulta general, consta de traer los 3 registros con puntuación más alta**

```php
$premiacion = Preliminar::first()->orderBy('preliminar', 'desc')->where('competencia', $evento)->take(3)->get();
```

**Y en esta segunda consulta debo traer los datos que necesito omitiendo algunos registros de la primera consulta**

```php
$ids = Preliminar::select('id_preliminar')->where('id_preliminar','1')->get();

$AA = Preliminar::orderBy('preliminar', 'desc')->where('competencia', $evento)->where('cat_principal','AA')->where('id_preliminar','not like', $ids)->get();
```

Declaro `$ids` trayendo el id que quiero omitir, pero al ejecutar mi consulta `$AA` no detecta el id que genere, cuando sustituyo `$ids` por un campo como '1' funciona.

¿Algún problema que tenga mi código? ¿Al llamar la variable en la consulta? ¿La manera en que traigo el id? ¿Otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Varias cosas que veo... En la primera consulta usas ```first()``` esto hace que solo obtengas un valor, por lo que el ```take(3)``` no estaria funcionando. Asique primero deberias quitar el ```first()```, si esto esta funcionando sin quitarlo, quitalo igualmente porque se estara invalidando con la parte del ```take(3)->get()```

Comment: Por otro lado, no usas para nada lo que coges en ```$premiacion```, por lo que no entiendo para que lo pones... si lo que pretendes es construir ```$ids``` con lo obtenido en ```$premiacion``` deberias meter todos en el where con un ```whereIn()``` o un ```orWhere()```. Y por ultimo en ```$AA``` igual te sirve mas en vez de usar un ```where()``` un ```whereNotIn()```

Comment: Si especificas mas tu problema para poder reproducirlo te pongo una respuesta mas clara, pero no tengo claro donde reside el error del todo...

Comment: $premiacion lo uso para llenar mi primer tabla y $AA para llenar mi segunda tabla.  Como te comento, al generar mi segunda tabla se tiene que generar omitiendo los datos de $premiacion que solo arroja tres registros, estos tres no deben salir en la segunda tabla.

Comment: La idea seria recoger los tres datos de $premiacion y omitirlos directamente en $AA, pero bueno, la implementación de $ids simplemente la estaba probando para ver si puedo recoger el id en una subconsulta y ejecutarla en $AA. Pero de ninguna de las dos formas he podido hacer que funcione

Answer (score 1):

Además de lo que ya te mencionaron en los comentarios bajo la pregunta, el otro problema es que en `$ids` vas a tener una colección de objetos `Preliminar`, por lo cual `->where('id_preliminar','not like', $ids)` siempre va a ser verdadero porque un entero (`id_preliminar`) nunca va a ser `like` una colección de objetos.

Siguiendo tu misma lógica, podrías usar [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck) para recuperar todos los valores de una clave dada.

```
$premiacion = Preliminar::where('competencia', $evento)
    ->take(3)
    ->orderBy('preliminar', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Aquí, recuperaremos una colección de la llave `id_preliminar` de la colección `$premiacion`:

```
$ids_que_no_quiero_incluir = $premiacion->pluck('id_preliminar');
```

Luego transformas esa colección en un array para usarla en un [whereNotIn](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

```
$AA = Preliminar::orderBy('preliminar', 'desc')
    ->where('competencia', $evento)
    ->where('cat_principal','AA')
    ->whereNotIn('id_preliminar', $ids_que_no_quiero_incluir->toArray())
    ->get();
```

O salteandote el paso de `$ids_que_no_quiero_incluir`:

```
$AA = Preliminar::orderBy('preliminar', 'desc')
    ->where('competencia', $evento)
    ->where('cat_principal','AA')
    ->whereNotIn('id_preliminar', $premiacion->pluck('id_preliminar')->toArray())
    ->get();
```

Comment: Interesante, desconocia la existencia de `pluck`. Tu respuesta parece correcta en base a lo que podemos ver y deducir de la pregunta. Gracias por ampliar mis respuestas de los comentarios :)

Comment: @adrigo sí, aunque es raro hacer dos consultas seguidas a la misma tabla, creo que sería lo más eficiente para el caso. Vale, sólo paso por aquí en mis ratos libres, ví las aclaraciones de los comentarios y respondí

Comment: Yo ando bastante por aqui, vi el codigo y me parecio un poco mejorable y quise explicar las cosas con respecto a lo que se, seguramente no sea el mejor pero si puedo aportar algo ni tan mal.